# Android Html.ImageGetter тормозит скроллинг

Tags: android, изображения, scrollview

У меня есть ScrollView, в нем программно создается TextView с текстом и картинками, который берётся из string.xml файла. Вот таким образом:

```
spanned = Html.fromHtml(byIdName(getContext(), text), new Html.ImageGetter() {

                public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                    Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
                    int identifier = resources.getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
                    Drawable res = resources.getDrawable(identifier);
                    res.setBounds(0, 0, px, hx);
                    return res;
                }
            }, null);
```

И если картинок больше четырех, то когда на экране пятая, скроллинг (прокрутка) начинает неприятно подтормаживать. Когда пятая (или последующие) картинка уходит за пределы экрана, то скроллинг опять плавный. 
 С первыми четырьмя картинками такой проблемы нет.

Никак не могу докопаться, в чем дело и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы делаете это в основном потоке?Пробовали выносить в отдельный поток?

Comment: Пробовал, выносил в new Thread, получается то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Не помню кто, но где-то тут читал, что есть такие проблемы со ScrollView и именно с добавлением картинок, поэтому выбор по реализации подобной задачи со списком пал на RecycleView и отдельный адаптер для управления наполнением этого списка (пропадают тормоза). Наполнение адаптера лучше всего возложить на бэграунд процесс (читай, AsyncTask).